# config_cache_enabled Errors

Tags: zend-framework2

Using Zend Framework 2.1

When I set `'config_cache_enabled' => true` inside of my `application.config.php`

It's returning the following error:

`Warning:  var_export does not handle circular references in /usr/local/apache/vhosts/otwebsoft_admin/vendor/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/AbstractListener.php on line 67`

After a few refreshes of the page then I get this:

`Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Apc::__set_state() in /usr/local/apache/vhosts/otwebsoft_admin/data/cache/module-config-cache.otwebsoft.php on line 181`

I can see now that file is created on the server. Of course setting the value back to false in the config removes all the errors. But now we have loss of cacheing functionality.

Yes, I am using the APC Adapter for my cache.

Reading the PHP documentation it recommends to use serialize. So I looked at the source code and changed the var_export to serialize and that removes that error, but it brings back the 2nd error listed here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any closures or object instances in your configuration? This can lead to caching errors...

Comment: Here is what I have in two files... Sorry the terminology confuses me sometimes. https://gist.github.com/4694254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figured this out. I don't know why it took me so long but everything makes sense now.

So a closure would be something like:

```
'example' => factory()
{
    return new Example();
}
```

Where-as I should be using (for example):

```
'example' => 'Module/Service/Example'
```

After I removed all the closures I'm now able to use

```
'config_cache_enabled' => true
```