# Zend Framework 2 - Cache-conform service factories

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

The zend file `application.config.php` offers some way to cache the config, which I find very nice for a production system:

```
return array(
        'modules' => array(
                'Application',
        ),
        'module_listener_options' => array(
                'module_paths' => array(
                        './module',
                        './vendor'
                ),
                'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'),
                'config_cache_enabled' => true,
                'config_cache_key' => md5('config'),
                'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
                'module_map_cache_key' => md5('module_map'),
                'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
        ),
);
```

However, activating that leads immediately to errors like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()
```

This has to do with factories written as closures, like these:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'auth.service' => function($sm) {
            /* hic sunt ponies */
        },
    ),
),
```

Unfortunately, [the](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2818) [issues](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/issues/181) [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653485/config-cache-enabled-errors) tell me *why* this error happens, but not how to resolve it.

How can I rework this and similar `factories` so the cache will work with them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rework your factory closures to factory classes.

#### Config

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'auth.service' => \Fully\Qualified\NS\AuthFactory::class,
    ),
),
```

#### Factory

```
namespace Fully\Qualified\NS;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class AuthFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        // create your object and set dependencies
        return $object
    }
}
```

Besides this approach making caching possible, another advantage is that PHP will parse your config faster since it doesn't have to create a Closure class on each request for each [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).